# How to solve "Failed to deploy the manifest file to the Exchange server. The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."?

Tags: development, visual-studio, office-web-apps, outlook-add-in

I am getting below error while running the outlook web app solution.

> Failed to deploy the manifest file to the Exchange server.  The
>   request failed. The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad
>   Request.

What I am trying?

I created a new solution and hit F5 without modifying the code. And it gave me below error.

[image]

I am not getting any reference on the web. If you have any solution or reference link then please feel free to share.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?